# Can placeholder text color in a TextBox in Winforms be changed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the color of the placeholder text in a textbox but cant seem to find a way to do it. Is it possible to change it ?

Comment: You can stop looking, not an option.  It is a theme color that applies to all programs on your machine.  If you want to find out how to change the theme on your machine then ask at superuser.com

Comment: Do you mean the CueBanner color or the highlight color? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a Placeholder text property in WinForms (Someone correct me if I had missed this)

My way of doing this will be to add 2 event handlers, one for `Enter` event and another for `Leave` event

```
private void textbox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(textbox1.Text == "my_placeholder_text")
  {
      textbox1.Text = "";
      textbox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }
}


private void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(textbox1.Text == "")
  {
      textbox1.Text = "my_placeholder_text";
      textbox1.ForeColor = Color.LightBlue;  //or whatever color your want to set
  }
}
```

Additionally, if you wish to use this for multiple textboxes, create your own textbox control inheriting from `System.Windows.Forms.UI.TextBox` class and add two properties to it `PlaceholderText` and `PlaceholderColor`

```
class myTextBox: System.Windows.Forms.UI.TextBox
{
  public string PlaceholderText {get; set;} = "";
  public Color PlaceholderColor {get; set;} = Color.Gray;

  protected void override OnEnter(EventArgs e)
  {
    if(this.Text == PlaceholderText)
    {
      this.Text = "";
      this.Color = this.ForeColor;
    }
  }

  protected void override OnLeave(EventArgs e)
  {
    if(this.Text == "")
    {
      this.Text = PlaceholderText;
      this.Color = this.PlaceholderColor;
    }
  }
}
```

*PS: All code typed here, so typos and some errors might occur.*